# Wifi turns on and off in irregular intervalson Lenovo Thinkpad T460

Tags: release-hera, wifi, networking, hardware

I just installed EOS Hera 5 on the Thinkpad T460 and EOS runs fine so far but for one issue:
The wifi gets dropped and picks up in irregular intervals - which is more than annoying.
I tried the Broadcom proprietary driver install, the battery save settings in BIOS and EOS but nothing works.
Only when I use my cell as a hotspot will it work fine. Does the distance to the wifi router make it a problem since I don#t get full network bars?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Wi-Fi chip it has? Intel AC-8260 or  Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 WLAN?

Comment: This is really interesting: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Lenovo+ThinkPad+T460s+Wi-Fi+Card+Replacement/127502

Comment: One more link worth to read: https://ask.metafilter.com/341570/Finding-a-new-wireless-card-for-a-Thinkpad-T460

Comment: If you will provide what Wi-Fi chip you have I will be able to find a proper firmware and provide a tutorial, however I doubt it will help, just because of the two above links. They explained that the chip from vendor is just sh....